# JPA, SQlite no such table: SEQUENCE

Tags: sql, sqlite, jpa

I have a problem with JPA and SQlite.

I have created an Entity from Table. My generated Entity looks like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="sqliteTestTable")
    public class Test implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id  
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;



        public Test() {
        }
        ------
    }
```

When i try to persist a few Test objects i get following error:
(I have executed the same code on mysql without problems)

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: no such table: SEQUENCE
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, SEQ_GEN_TABLE]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_TABLE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: There is no GenerationType.ID. What's the actual code?

Comment: Thats in the actual code: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

Comment: When i change the GenerationType to IDENTITY this error occurse: Exception Description: SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY: platform DatabasePlatform does not support NativeSequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDENTITY will default to TABLE if IDENTITY is not supported in the database platform.

For TABLE you need to have a sequence table created.  If you have ElipseLink create your tables it will automatically be created for you, otherwise you need to create it yourself.

If SQlite has IDENTITY support, then you can create your own DatabasePlatform subclass that adds the identity support.

In general I would never recommend using IDENTITY, it does not support pre-allocation and will lead to poor performance.

Answer (score 3):

sqlite uses the table sqlite_sequence for AUTOINCREMENT field

replace:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

with

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="sqlite")
@TableGenerator(name="sqlite", table="sqlite_sequence",
    pkColumnName="name", valueColumnName="seq",
    pkColumnValue="sqliteTestTable")
```

If you are using multiple tables then the generators have to be unique names. With a new table, there is no sqlite_sequence record so you have to create yourself.

```
insert into sqlite_sequence (name,seq) values ("sqliteTestTable",1);
```

Comment: Good advice! 
In my case from this strategy derived a problem with the autoincrement value allocation size; if you are in the same situation just add the `initialValue=1, allocationSize=1` elements (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573547))